# What does “It’s always a pig in a poke. So why not a pig who pokes?”mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In an article under the title, “Trump the disrupter,” (New York Times August 10 issue), Op-ed columnist, Maureen Dowd wrote:

> “It is really hard to know who you’re electing. That’s because you
>   can’t foresee what crises will crop up, or what gremlins of insecurity
>   and perversity the White House will inevitably elicit in presidential
>   psyches.
>
> You can have a candidate like W., after sincerely telling us he will
>   have a “humble” foreign policy, proceed to stumble jejunely into
>   decades-long wars in the Middle East. You can have a charming newcomer
>   like Barack Obama, ascending like a political Pegasus, who loses
>   altitude because it turns out he disdains politics. **It’s always a pig
>   in a poke. So why not a pig who pokes?**”
>   http://www.nytimes.com/2015/08/09/opinion/sunday/maureen-dowd-trump-the-disrupter.html?

I know “a pig in a poke” as a cliché. But I cannot make out what the next line - "Why not a pig who pokes” means?

Does it mean a would-be President is allowed to become a chameleon once he attains the throne? What does the second “poke” as a verb mean?

P.S.

As the second thought after rereading the quote, I came to think “Why not a pig who pokes” means “Isn't it good to have a pig who pokes out the poke and reveals what he really is, or attempts?” But I’m not sure of whether it’s on the mark or not.

Comment: No one has mentioned this so far, so I will. Consider the fact that Mr Donald Trump, who  is running for candidacy,  is a renowned opportunist, and sexist. Women often call sexist men "pigs", the expression "male chauvinist pig" is probably an epithet that Mr Trump wears with a certain pride. So it's quite a clever use of image, folklore and clichés all rolled in one.

Comment: It's just a neat little play on words. A pig in a poke is when you don't know if you are getting what you paid for. And then she turns it round and says it's not only a real pig, it's a pig with attitude.

Comment: Frankly, as a play on words it's not a very good one.

Comment: Indeed.  One might even say it's ham-fisted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is play on the old saying [a pig in a poke](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-pig-in-a-poke.html) that is something you buy without actually seeing what it really is. [image]

A pig who [pokes](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poke) is a pig who:

[image]

> - To thrust forward; appear: The child's head poked from under the blankets. (AHD)

So you know in advance who you are voting for.

The author  is saying, whenever we vote for a President, we don't actually know who we are voting for (a pig in the poke) so why not a pig who pokes, a candidate who shows his real nature/intentions during their campaign rather than after being elected.

Answer (score 5):

It means:  "Since you can never really tell what you're getting when you go to the polls, why NOT vote for a bad-mannered, bad-tempered, boorish person who throws personal insults at everyone who disagrees with him?"

The author is arguing that many people see casting a ballot as essentially a blind choice - like "buying a pig in a poke" - so the fact that a candidate behaves like a pig during the campaign may not be considered a disqualification by some voters.

Answer (score 4):

"Pig in a poke" meaning "something hidden" has already been answered. Another meaning of "poke" was a an type of women's bonnet, which hid the face from view. There are some 18th century cartoons here: http://mikerendell.com/a-pig-in-a-poke-an-eighteenth-century-view/

For "A pig who pokes", The "pig" part seems straightforward: "Why not a pig...." = "Why not somebody who behaves like a pig," or "who looks like a pig" (see Google images for lots of examples.)

There are several meanings of "poke" that are relevant as well as the literal one of "jab" or "prod":

"Poke a fire" = "cause something to blaze up" (e.g. "Trump poked the immigration fire")

"Poke around" or "Poke ones nose into" = "go searching for something", often used in the sense of "go looking for trouble."

"Take a poke at someone" = literally or metaphorically "hit someone", or "have sex with someone" (not necessarily with their consent).

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poke

Comment: +1 I think it's fair to suggest that Mr. Trump is known for his *poking* - verbally jabbing and assaulting those he dislikes or disagrees with.

Comment: A poke is a bag. "And then he drew a dial [clock] [from his poke](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/As_You_Like_It/Act_II)." The cartoonist is making a pun on "pig in a poke" and a "poke bonnet".

Comment: To "poke" is also sometimes used as a sexual innuendo (with the obvious meaning) though I think that's much less common and probably not what the original author was intending.

Answer (score 2):

A poke is a bag.  When I worked on a hop-farm, the light hessian bags into which the hop-flowers were fed were called *pokes*.  Oddly, the very large, densely-woven, tubular bags into which the dried flowers were pressed were called *pockets*, although you'd think that *pocket* was a diminutive of *poke*. So buying a pig in a poke was buying a pig in a bag, unseen.  Perhaps small pigs *were* once carried to market in bags.

Comment: Related to French *poche* (pocket).

Comment: The problem with buying a pig in a poke is that it may turn out to be a cat or a rat or some such.

Comment: @HotLicks Hence the corresponding Spanish saying of *dar/comprar/tomar gato por liebre* meaning “giving/buying/taking (a) cat for (a) hare”.  So our don’t buy a pig in a poke is their don’t buy a cat for a hare, and for exactly the same reason.

Comment: This is all well and true, but it completely ignores the actual question. Yoichi already says that he understands what _pig in a poke_ means (and asking for that would be GR, too, since it's in any decent dictionary), but doesn't get “why not a pig that pokes?”.

Comment: In the West of Scotland, we still refer to a bag as a poke. Still brings alarm to strangers' faces when a shopkeeper asks "Do you want a poke with that?"

Comment: @LaconicDroid If I could upvote that 10 times I would.

Comment: Really interesting but not in the least an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "buying (or selling) a pig in a poke" refers to buying something you can't inspect and trusting that it really is as described. "You can't open the bag here, since the piglet might escape, but I promise that it's a healthy little one, definitely worth the price I'm asking for it."

Obviously, the seller may have been lying -- the thing in the bag might not even be a pig. Hence the phrase generally does imply a high (or at best unknown) probability of fraud. It's often used to describe vague political promises, for example.

"Why not a pig who pokes" is just wordplay based on this traditional phrase. To be sure if the intended meaning (if any), I'd need to see it in context.

Comment: #mary-loua@ tnx, fixed.

Comment: Just a polite suggestion. If you need the context, wouldn't it be better to ask for it in a comment and then answer when you have the vital information. Otherwise your answer is merely repeating the question. No offence meant, and I hope none taken :-)

Comment: @chaslyfromuk: I don't actually think we need the context; I believe my answer is sufficient and the OP can figure out the rest easily enough.